# How to install a Vue 2 package from github that it is not on NPM?

Tags: npm, vuejs2, typeahead

I'm working on a personal Vue 2 project and I need to update the [vue-typeahead-bootstrap](https://github.com/mattzollinhofer/vue-typeahead-bootstrap) package from 2.12.0 to 2.13.0, but only the 2.12.0 is published on NPM. I really need the updates included on the 2.13.0.

How can I install a package from github without NPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install a GitHub repo with a tag:

`npm install github:mattzollinhofer/vue-typeahead-bootstrap#2.13.0`